# copy tree with gradle and change structure?

Tags: gradle, build, copy, rename

Can gradle alter the structure of the tree while copying?

**original**

- mod/a/src
- mod/b/src

**desired**

- dest/mod-a/source
- dest/mod-b/source
- dest/mod-c/source

I'm not sure where I should create a closure and override the copy tree logic

I'd like to do the gradle equivalent of ant's globmapper functionality

```
<property name="from.dir" location=".."/>      
<property name="to.dir" location="dbutil"/>
<copy>
    <fileset dir="${from.dir}" ... />
    <globmapper from="${from.dir}/*/db" to="${to.dir}"/> 
</copy>
```

Thanks

Peter

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When changing file name, rename seems a good approach.  When changing path you can override *eachFile* and modify the destination path.

This works pretty well.

```
    copy {
    from("${sourceDir}") {
        include 'modules/**/**'
    }
    into(destDir)
    eachFile {details ->

        // Top Level Modules
        def targetPath = rawPathToModulesPath(details.path)
        details.path = targetPath
    }
}
....
def rawPathToModulesPath(def path) {
// Standard case modules/name/src -> module-name/src
def modified=path.replaceAll('modules/([^/]+)/.*src/(java/)?(.*)', {"module-${it[1]}/src/${it[3]}"})
return modified
}
```

Comment: This one works for me but it creates the original directories, too, which remain empty.

Comment: Try setting `setIncludeEmptyDirs(false)`

Comment: FYI if you want to just keep the filename and put it into the target directory, `details.path = details.name`

Comment: @eastwater It's just moving files, so it should be agnostic as to source v resources v a directory filled with mp3s.

Answer (score 2):

Please see sample below. Gradle 4.3 does not have rename/move methods, so we can do renaming on the fly.

What was happened:

1. Load file tree into the memory. I used zip file from dependencies in my example
2. Filter items, which are in the target folder
3. All result items will have the same prefix: if we filter files from directory "A/B/C/", then all files will be like "A/B/C/file.txt" or "A/B/C/D/file.txt". E.g. all of them will start with the same words
4. In the last statement *eachFile* we will change final name by cutting the directory prefix (e.g. we will cut "A/B/C").
5. **Important:** use type of task "Copy", which has optimizations for incremental compilation. Gradle will not do file copy if all of items below are true:

   - Input is the same (for my case - all dependencies of scope "nativeDependenciesScope") with previous build
   - Your function returned the same items with the previous build
   - Destination folder has the same file hashes, with the previous build

```groovy
task copyNativeDependencies(type: Copy) {
    includeEmptyDirs = false
    def subfolderToUse = "win32Subfolder"

    def nativePack = configurations.nativeDependenciesScope.singleFile // result - single dependency file

    def nativeFiles = zipTree(nativePack).matching { include subfolderToUse + "/*" } // result - filtered file tree

    from nativeFiles
    into 'build/native_libs'
    eachFile {
        print(it.path)

        // we filtered this folder above, e.g. all files will start from the same folder name
        it.path = it.path.replaceFirst("$subfolderToUse/", "")
    }
}

// and don't forget to link this task for something mandatory
test.dependsOn(copyNativeDependencies)
run.dependsOn(copyNativeDependencies)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following works, but is there a more gradle-ish way to do this?

```
    ant.copy(todir: destDir) {
      fileset( dir: "${srcDir}/module", includes: '**/src/**')
      regexpmapper(from: '^(.*)/src/(.*)$', to: /module-\1\/src\/\2/)
    }
```

Comment: Why can't we use `globmapper`?

Comment: Probably could. Perhaps that is a more truly gradle approach. Got an example?