# gradle processResources: file path conversion

Tags: gradle, process, path, resources

Grade: how to customize processResources to change the resource file path in the jar?

For example:

```
foo/a.xml  --> foo/bar/a.xml
```

something similar to:

[copy tree with gradle and change structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13296986/copy-tree-with-gradle-and-change-structure)

```
copy {
   from("${sourceDir}") {
       include 'modules/**/**'
   }
   into(destDir)
   eachFile {details ->

       // Top Level Modules
       def targetPath = rawPathToModulesPath(details.path)
       details.path = targetPath
   }
}

....
def rawPathToModulesPath(def path) {
   // Standard case modules/name/src -> module-name/src
   def modified=path.replaceAll('modules/([^/]+)/.*src/(java/)?(.*)', {"module-${it[1]}/src/${it[3]}"})
   return modified
}
```

How to add this in processResources? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`processResources` is a task of type `Copy`. Therefore you should be able to do

```
processResources {
   eachFile {details ->
       // Top Level Modules
       def targetPath = rawPathToModulesPath(details.path)
       details.path = targetPath
   }
}
```